# How crop image fit to content of image?

Tags: vb.net

I have a image as below:

[image]

I want crop image fit to content , remove white area.

Result:

[image]

This is my code , it can crop image

```
Dim fileName = "D:\2018\ori_image.jpg"
        Dim fileNameres = "D:\2018\res_image.jpg"
        Dim CropRect As New System.Drawing.Rectangle(0, 0, 200, 320)
        Dim OriginalImage = System.Drawing.Image.FromFile(fileName)
        Dim CropImage = New Bitmap(CropRect.Width, CropRect.Height)
        Using grp = Graphics.FromImage(CropImage)
            grp.DrawImage(OriginalImage, New System.Drawing.Rectangle(0, 0, CropRect.Width, CropRect.Height), CropRect, GraphicsUnit.Pixel)
            OriginalImage.Dispose()
            CropImage.Save(fileNameres)
        End Using
```

Now, How can get Position Start and Size content of Image?
Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the following code to remove the unwanted area:

```
Public Function CropUnwantedBackground(ByVal bmp As Bitmap) As Bitmap
    Dim backColor = GetMatchedBackColor(bmp)

    If backColor.HasValue Then
        Dim bounds = GetImageBounds(bmp, backColor)
        Dim diffX = bounds(1).X - bounds(0).X + 1
        Dim diffY = bounds(1).Y - bounds(0).Y + 1
        Dim croppedBmp = New Bitmap(diffX, diffY)
        Dim g = Graphics.FromImage(croppedBmp)
        Dim destRect = New Rectangle(0, 0, croppedBmp.Width, croppedBmp.Height)
        Dim srcRect = New Rectangle(bounds(0).X, bounds(0).Y, diffX, diffY)
        g.DrawImage(bmp, destRect, srcRect, GraphicsUnit.Pixel)
        Return croppedBmp
    Else
        Return bmp
    End If
End Function

Private Function GetImageBounds(ByVal bmp As Bitmap, ByVal backColor As Color?) As Point()
    Dim c As Color
    Dim width As Integer = bmp.Width, height As Integer = bmp.Height
    Dim upperLeftPointFounded As Boolean = False
    Dim bounds = New Point(1) {}

    For y As Integer = 0 To height - 1

        For x As Integer = 0 To width - 1
            c = bmp.GetPixel(x, y)
            Dim sameAsBackColor As Boolean = ((c.R <= backColor.Value.R * 1.1 AndAlso c.R >= backColor.Value.R * 0.9) AndAlso (c.G <= backColor.Value.G * 1.1 AndAlso c.G >= backColor.Value.G * 0.9) AndAlso (c.B <= backColor.Value.B * 1.1 AndAlso c.B >= backColor.Value.B * 0.9))

            If Not sameAsBackColor Then

                If Not upperLeftPointFounded Then
                    bounds(0) = New Point(x, y)
                    bounds(1) = New Point(x, y)
                    upperLeftPointFounded = True
                Else

                    If x > bounds(1).X Then
                        bounds(1).X = x
                    ElseIf x < bounds(0).X Then
                        bounds(0).X = x
                    End If

                    If y >= bounds(1).Y Then bounds(1).Y = y
                End If
            End If
        Next
    Next

    Return bounds
End Function

Private Function GetMatchedBackColor(ByVal bmp As Bitmap) As Color?
    Dim corners = New Point() {New Point(0, 0), New Point(0, bmp.Height - 1), New Point(bmp.Width - 1, 0), New Point(bmp.Width - 1, bmp.Height - 1)}

    For i As Integer = 0 To 4 - 1
        Dim cornerMatched = 0
        Dim backColor = bmp.GetPixel(corners(i).X, corners(i).Y)

        For j As Integer = 0 To 4 - 1
            Dim cornerColor = bmp.GetPixel(corners(j).X, corners(j).Y)

            If (cornerColor.R <= backColor.R * 1.1 AndAlso cornerColor.R >= backColor.R * 0.9) AndAlso (cornerColor.G <= backColor.G * 1.1 AndAlso cornerColor.G >= backColor.G * 0.9) AndAlso (cornerColor.B <= backColor.B * 1.1 AndAlso cornerColor.B >= backColor.B * 0.9) Then
                cornerMatched += 1
            End If
        Next

        If cornerMatched > 2 Then
            Return backColor
        End If
    Next

    Return Nothing
End Function
```

Something like this should work. Just call `CropUnwantedBackground`:

```
Dim fileName = "D:\2018\ori_image.jpg"
Dim fileNameres = "D:\2018\res_image.jpg"
Dim CropRect As New System.Drawing.Rectangle(0, 0, 200, 320)
Dim OriginalImage = System.Drawing.Image.FromFile(fileName)
Dim ImageWithoutWhiteArea = CropUnwantedBackground(OriginalImage)
ImageWithoutWhiteArea.Save(fileNameres)
```